# cannot connect mysql DB in my host

Tags: mysql, database, hosting, localhost

I just created a site at freewebhosting.com, upload a new mediawiki project and opened it for first time. The installation goes fine until I have to connect my DB.

freewebhosting provided me the data I should need:

DataBase name: db_name
DataBase username: db_user
DataBase password: db_pass
DataBase host: localhost

I put all these data correctly but cannot connect:
DB connection error: Access denied for user 'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (localhost).

It must be not that hard lol, but I dont know what should be. The only odd thing I see there i DataBase host: localhost. Is this right? I mean it is trying to connect to my site and not to my localhost?

Regards.

Comment: Indeed, you cannot connect to `localhost` to access a remote database (unless you are working on a remote terminal like SSH). It should be the IP of the server that hosts your database

Comment: localhost should be changed to actual address/ip of your new db

Comment: any trick on how to get IP? As I said the information they provide me is localhost... MOFOs

Comment: Hmmm... It seems that you dont have permission enough. Have you contact them? Or for easier, you may ask them to install it for you.

Answer (score 0):

LoL. Just tried again and worked. 
I guess they should have updated my db information a few hours after setting it up. Appreciate everybody.